# Showing results from a select statement when PK isnt referenced in another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 database tables, one containing user information and another containing the specific corporate roles they are performing.

Some of the fields contained in these DB's are as follows:

**Table1: UserInformation**
`Username, name, surname, RoleID (FK Reference to Table2) etc`

**Table2: RoleInformation**
`ID (PK and ref from Table 1 RoleID), RoleName etc`

***The program:***

I have a dropdown which I am populating with the results of a **SQL query**.
The program I am writing will be used by HR to assign unused company roles to selected company users in order to kick off other processes within the company.

I am very unexperienced thus far with SQL only being able to write very little more complicated than an extra long insert statement lol
Can someone help me structure a SQL query that returns roles that are not currently assigned to a user.

In pseudocode:

```
select RoleName 
from Table2 
where the ID is not referenced/used in Table1
```

I hope I described the scenario correctly...

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`

```
select RoleName 
  from Table2 t2
  where not exists (select 1 
                      from Table1 t1 
                     where t1.RoleID = t2.RoleInformationID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subselect and the IN operator, something like:

```
select RoleName from Table2 where RoleInformationID not in (select distinct(RoleID) from Table1 )
```